# Int32.Parse vs int.Parse

Tags: c#, coding-style

It is a common practice to use C# type aliases instead of CTS System.* types (`int` instead of `Int32` and `string` instead of `String`). However it's not clear to me what to use to call a static method of a type in this case: an alias or a system type.

Microsoft does not seem to define any guidelies to use aliases instead of System types. But in MSDN aliases are used for variables and CTS equivalents are used for static calls. For example [MSDN: Parsing Numeric Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xbtzcc4w.aspx)

```
int number;
Int32.TryParse(value, out number);
```

StyleCop defines the contrary in [SA1121](http://stylecop.soyuz5.com/SA1121.html) - to always use aliases. So `int.Parse` is ok while `Int32.Parse` is not.

This question is a matter of style (in my opinion). But I don't understand reasons to use CTS type for static calls.

Comment: I would second StyleCop's suggestion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I personally always use full class names for static method calls. This underlines the fact that they are in fact classes that contain pieces of code instead of simplest possible (primitive) data which the aliases imply.

I always use aliases for variables.

Comment: Have been revising my questions and found this was not accepted. Your answer gives the reasonable explaination to do `Int32.Something`. Although I prefer the other way :)

Answer (score 6):

There is absolutely no technical difference, just coding style. Personally I advocate `int.Parse`, but there are many well-known [experts](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jeffreyr/default.aspx) that prefer the opposite.

Comment: I prefer `Int32.Parse`, however I am no expert. :)

Comment: @Default No, you're just not well-known.  :-)

Comment: I would be interested to here what is the reasoning behind using the alias. I know the reasoning behind using full names (see my answer) but I have never heard the reasoning for aliases.

Comment: @Stilgar Reasoning behind using aliases is just using aliases everywhere. And besides `long var = Int64.Parse("1");` is less intuitive than `long var = long.Parse("1");`

Comment: @Stilgar: I wouldn't say *the* reasoning really. IMHO the reason you provide doesn't have real substance. A reason I have heard that I can agree with is that e.g. `Int64` makes it immediately clear what the width of the type is, while `long` does not. If you believe it does, ask a C++ developer what they think.

Comment: The only reason I can think in favor of aliases is that you can use them without `using` statement.

Comment: @Stilgar IMO a reason isn't really necessary. I can read both easily and without confusion, I just prefer using aliases - muscle memory makes me type `int` faster than `Int32`. Of course, there is always the reason of saving your limited keystrokes: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/DoTheyDeserveTheGiftOfYourKeystrokes.aspx

Comment: @Mike with this reasoning you can call static methods on variables... just use variables everywhere (I know it is not possible to call a static method on a variable in C# but it is in C++ and Java but is considered bad practice)

Comment: @Jon this makes sense in C++ but not in C#. What is more we are talking about static methods here so the size of the data is not an issue.

Comment: @Stilgar: Not an issue? Quick, does `long.Parse("5000000000")` work or not? If you had a C++ background you would *immediately* do a double take on that. But `Int64.Parse` would be a no-brainer.

Comment: So what about String.IsNullOrEmpty? Does the size matter there? :)

Comment: @Stilgar: Nope :) At that point it's just a matter of being consistent.

Comment: @Stilgar In case of `int number = int.Parse(...)` you don't have a variable yet to call Parse on.

Comment: @Mike It should work the other way round. All static methods in your project are called by class name except for Parse... doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Stilgar Ok why not start using Int32 type for variables to be totally consistent. Or I don't get your point

Comment: My point is that aliases like int, string point out that this type has special treatment by the compiler, that it is a kind of primitive building block, and static methods for these types are not in fact any different from any other static method and also are contain code not data (therefore no special treatment). Basically aliases point out primitiveness and static methods are not primitive in any way even for primitive types. I know that "primitive types" is not exact term in the context of .NET and I use it as "a type with special treatment by the compiler and the runtime"

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest to use `int.Parse(...)` instead of `int32`.If you immagine someone 
read your code running it  on 64 bit machine, and it's probbale that he is not aware of that `int32` and `int` are just *aliases*, it will make him to do a wrong assumptions.

In other words, even if from functional  point of view there is no any difference, to avoid ambiguity in the code (referencies to presumably 32 bit code) I would suggest to use `int.Parse(..)`

Comment: This bares no relationship to static methods since the size of the data is related to the variable not to the method call. In fact you can do long i = int.Parse(...). What is more how would you justify String.IsNullOrEmpty vs string.IsNullOrEmpty?

Comment: @Stilgar: I'm not talking about the data in any its rapresentation. I'm talking about **only** the name: int32 versus int. Variables, sizes of variable, accessor types and all other stuff is not related to this post.